# Java JTable or JInternal Frame auto reload/Refresh

Tags: java, swing, jtable

why JTable data updated when JInternalframe closed and then opened again

```
 public void viewTabelMejaBayar(String mejahe){
    //mejahe = textNomeja.getText();
    try {
        konek = Koneksi.getKoneksi();
        state = konek.createStatement();
```

String query = "select * from tbtrans where stdpr='1' AND stkasir='0' AND  nomeja='"+mejahe+"' ";

ResultSet result= state.executeQuery(query);

```
         while(result.next()){

            Kasir p = new Kasir();

            p.setNokey(result.getString("nokey"));//1
            p.setNovisitor(result.getString("novisitor")); //2
            p.setNomeja(result.getInt("nomeja")); //3
            p.setNoantri(result.getInt("noantri"));//4
            p.setAddedpeg(result.getString("addedpeg"));//5
            p.setKdmc(result.getInt("kdmc"));//6
            p.setMncafe(result.getString("mncafe"));//7
            p.setKatmenu(result.getString("katmenu"));//8

            p.setQty(result.getDouble("qty"));//9
            p.setHrg(result.getDouble("hrg"));//10
            p.setSubtotal(result.getDouble("subtotal"));//11
            p.setWorder(result.getString("worder"));//12
            p.setStord(result.getInt("stord"));//13
            p.setWsaji(result.getString("wsaji"));//14
            p.setStdpr(result.getInt("stdpr"));//15
            p.setStkasir(result.getInt("stkasir"));//16
            p.setPegkasir(result.getString("pegkasir"));//17 


            tableModelkas.add(p);
            //tableModelkas.fireTableDataChanged();
            //tableModelkas.fireTableChanged(null);

          }

     }
     catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

     } 
    //Pramusaji p = new Pramusaji();

}







bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent t) {

                    String str = t.getActionCommand();
                    int action = Integer.parseInt(str); 

                    int count = 0;
                    count = count +1;

                    switch (action){
                    case 1:
                        //if (e ==0){

            viewTabelMejaBayar("1");    //<---Data shown in the table 
            TotalBayare(); bt.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            textNomeja.setText("1"); 
            textBayar.requestFocus();



                        }
                        else{

                            if((count>0)&&(count<2)){

                    /*      }
                        *   if (count >=2){

                        *  bt.setEnabled(false);
                            * }
                            * bt.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                        }
                     */
                        repaint();
                        //ResetviewTabelMejaBayar();

                        break;
```

Comment: You're asking "why isn't my program working", and posting some code, but not enough code to allow most of us to fully understand your program or your problem. Please consider posting more relevant code, specifically a [minimal example program or mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is a small self-contained program that demonstrates your problem for us and has no extra code not related to your problem.

Comment: if stkasir = 1 the data should have been empty but the table can not be refreshed